# Loading Resources from the ClassPath in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

In Java I can have multiple instances of the some resource in the class path, and can access them thus:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Enumeration<URL> resources = loader.getResources("META-INF/services/myService.properties");
while(resources.hasMoreElements()){
    URL resource = resources.nextElement();
    // process each resource here
}
```

This allows use of service provider interfaces, where multiple implementations can be made available at runtime by dropping additional jars into the classpath.

Is there any equivalent to this in Java ME?

[UPDATE 2011-April-11]

If I could somehow get a list of jar files in the classpath, I could probably just pass the URLs to the Connector like this:

```
String [] jarFiles = ... // somehow I got this
for(int i = jarFiles.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    String url = "jar:file:"+jarFiles[i]+"!/META-INF/services/myService.properties";
    InputStream in = Connector.openInputStream(url);
    //process each resource here
}
```

Any idea how I might get all jar files in the classpath in J2ME?

Comment: Last I checked, you can't. But you can check for individual classes using Class.forName(..).

Comment: what do you need the .jars for?

Comment: I can get the classpath in J2SE using System.getProperty("java.class.path") - I will test if I can do this in JME.

Comment: This property does not seem to be present in JME. Anybody know if there is an equivalent?

Comment: @Thomas - I guess I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use Service Provider Interfaces in Java ME ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface ), where a library acquires an implementation at runtime from those available, but does not need to be bound to said implementation.

Comment: I would be using Class.forName to get a reference to the class once I have its name - the mechanisim I am looking for is for class name discovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it looks like the application must be contained within a single Jar file in a J2ME environment, so concepts like the classpath simply do not apply, meaning that this is not possible. All dependencies must be available at compile time.